# Extracting table data from Outlook email body

Tags: vba, email, outlook

I am getting Outlook email, were the **Body** contains a Table consisting of several string **Labels** and associated string **Text**. I want to extract three **Values** associated with the respective **Label**. The first two searchs are one column *right* of the **Label** and the last one is one row *below* the Label.
 I tried InStr() which works great for retrieving to the *right* of the **Label**, but it doesn't seem to work for the **Value** that is one cell *below* the **Label**.
 Can I use **MoveRight** and **MoveDown** from Excel/Work inside the *Outlook VBA* or use "**Range**(Rng.Offset(0, 1).Address).Value" and "**Range**(Rng.Offset(1, 0).Address).Value" to select the **Value** to the *right* and *below* in *Outlook VBA*.
 Key point here is that it is a structured table in the email body.

Comment: is body formatted HTML or RichText ?

Comment: this gives you the table object `Application.Inspectors(1).WordEditor.tables(1)` .... examine it in the watch window

Comment: I will check, but I don't think RichTest allows for tables.

Answer (score 1):

i have one email with a table that happens to be nested inside another table

that is why `Tables(1).Tables(1)` is used

the following code is for exploring the table.

first line highlights the cell in the table, so that you can check if you are referring the correct cell

the second and third lines shows how to get the value of a table cell

do not try to examine any `range` object in the watch window or the locals window. it causes outlook to crash. (no idea why)

if you want to explore any attributes of the `range` object then copy the email body to msWord. it does not crash when examining the range object

i could not find anything that refers to column headers

```
Sub aaaaa()

    Application.Inspectors(1).WordEditor.Tables(1).Tables(1).Rows(1).Cells(1).Select
    stop
    Debug.Print Application.Inspectors(1).WordEditor.Tables(1).Tables(2).Rows(3).Cells(4).Range.Text
    Debug.Print ActiveDocument.Tables(1).Tables(1).Cell(1, 1).Range.Text

End Sub
```

Comment: jsotola: appreciate the response. Yes Outlook is a bear in VBA. I am not comfortable with Debug.Print but I will give it a try. Ideal is to find respective Label cell, i.e., Name, Date, Address. Testing that would verify that it works. The actual _name_ is one cell to the right, the actual _date_ is one cell to the right, but the _address_ is one cell below the label and can have 1, 2, or 3 line entries in one cell.

Comment: all `debug.print` does, is to print into the "immediate window" .... there is nothing uncomfortable about it ... it is better than `msgbox` because the worksheet  does not get focus everytime you want an output .... it also allows `debug.print "abc", 123; 456, 789`

Comment: Jsotola: I ran the code as present with double Tables(1).

Comment: Jostola: the result was a "Runt-time Error 440, Array index out of bounds". If I changed .Inspector(1) to .Inspector, then the error changed to Error 438, Object doesn't support this propter or method. AND changing the one Table(2) to Table(1) had no effect. Restoring back to .Inspector(1) restored the Error to 440.

Comment: Jostola: Is the reason for the first .Table(1).Table(1) to address the ?eMail? as a table and the second .Table(1) as that of the .Body? I never thought of emails as a table, but it explains a lot of the code commends and structure if it is true.

Comment: Jostola: If I use Instr(_Label_, _Source_, _end-label_) to find the third _title label_. This is my problem in the code, finding the cell just below the third _title label_. Could I then use strText = ActiveDocument.Tables(1).Tables(2).Cell(1,0).Range.Text to select the cell just below the _title label_?

Comment: as i said in my answer, i have nested tables (one table inside another table) that is why i use `tables(1).tables(1)` ... i was expecting you to adjust your code to your situation. use this `Application.Inspectors(1).WordEditor.Tables(1).Select` .... it should highlight the first table. that should tell you if your data is in tables(1) ..... if it does highlight, then do `ActiveDocument.Tables(1).Cell(1, 1).select` .... that should highlight the first cell

Comment: Jostola: the first question is why I got a Error 440, Array index out of bounds. This seems to be associated with the double .tables(1) statement. Do I need to add a Dim statement to activate the Application.Inspectors(1)?

Comment: you do not have nested tables, so there is no Tables(1) object inside the first table...   imagine that you have a box that contains three boxes, and inside the three boxes are two pieces of paper each.  you refer to the first piece of paper in the second box as  `boxes(1).boxes(2).papers(1)`  .... the reason for `boxes` instead of `box` is because it is a `collection` of objects  .... in your case the `tables` collection, inside the tables(1) object, is empty